# How to show sub-categories in the Categories list

Tags: nopcommerce

How can I show sub-categories right in the Categories list, e.g.:

Root Category #1

- Sub Category #1
- Sub Category #2
- Sub Category #3

Root Category #2

- Sub Category #4
- Sub Category #5
- Sub Category #6

Nopcommerse v2.60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend CategoryNavigationModel with something like

```
public IList<CategoryNavigationModel> ChildCategoryNavigationModels { get; set; }
```

Then in CategoryNavigation action in CatalogController add one more loop for adding sub categories

```
foreach (var categoryNavigationModel in model)
                    categoryNavigationModel.ChildCategoryNavigationModels =
                        GetChildCategoryNavigationModel(new List<Category>(), categoryNavigationModel.Id, currentCategory, 0);
```

And then in CategoryNavigation.cshtml you can display sub categories within @foreach (var category in Model)

In that way:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var subCategory in category.ChildCategoryNavigationModels)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = subCategory.Id, SeName = subCategory.SeName })">
                @subCategory.Name
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Better to not alter NopCommerce code and try follow this approach http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/27/cheat-sheet-for-effectively-extending-nopcommerce/

Comment: The link is dead.
Here is the archive link :http://web.archive.org/web/20120627063144/http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/27/cheat-sheet-for-effectively-extending-nopcommerce